# Problem in creating Drop down product attribute in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, layered-navigation, patch-data

I have created a Data patch file to create the product drop down attribute with options. used the following code in it.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddTestAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
 private $moduleDataSetup;
 private $eavSetupFactory;
 public $_storeManager;
 private $logger;
 protected $_dir;
 const TYPE_BOOLEAN = "boolean";
 const TYPE_TEXT = "text";
 const TYPE_SELECT = "select";
 protected $_attributeFactory;
 protected $_eavAttribute;
  public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute  $eavAttribute
) {
    $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;  
    $this->_dir = $dir;
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function apply()
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

    $fileName = 'attributes_data.csv';
    $pubPath = $this->_dir->getPath('pub');
    $attributeFile = $pubPath.'/'.$fileName;
    $arrResult = array();
    if(($handle = fopen($attributeFile, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        $row = 1;
        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            $col_count = count($data);
            $arrResult[] = $data;               
            $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arrResult as $line) {
        if($i > 0){
            $attributeCode = $line[0];                    
            $attributeName = $line[1];
            $inputType = strtolower($line[2]);
            $options = $line[3];
            switch ($inputType) {
                case ($inputType == self::TYPE_BOOLEAN && isset($attributeCode)):  
                    $this->createBooleanAttribute($eavSetup,$attributeCode,$attributeName,$inputType);
                    break;
                case ($inputType == self::TYPE_SELECT && isset($attributeCode)):
                    $this->createSelectAttribute($eavSetup,$attributeCode,$attributeName,$inputType);
                    if(isset($options) && $options != '' ){
                       $optionName = explode (",", $options);
                        if(count($optionName) > 0){
                             $this->createAttributeOptions($eavSetup,$attributeCode,$optionName);
                        } 
                    }


                case ($inputType == self::TYPE_TEXT && isset($attributeCode)):
                    $this->createTextAttribute($eavSetup,$attributeCode,$attributeName,$inputType);
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->createTextAttribute($eavSetup,$attributeCode,$attributeName,$inputType);                    
            }
        }
        $i++;
    } 
}          
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getAliases()
{
    return [];
}

public function createSelectAttribute($eavSetup,$attributeCode,$attributeName,$inputType){ //,$options
$this->logger->info('-select Attribute---');
    $type = 'int';
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attributeCode,
        [
            'type' => $type,
            'group' => 'General',
            'backend' => 'int',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => $attributeName,
            'input' => $inputType,
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            "filterable_in_search" => 1,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false , 
            'system' => 1                    
        ]
    );
}

public function createTextAttribute($eavSetup,$attributeCode,$attributeName,$inputType){
    $type = 'text';
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attributeCode,
        [
            'type' => $type,
            'group' => 'Product Details',
            'attribute_set' =>  'Default',
            'label' => $attributeName,
            'backend' => '',
            'input' => $inputType,
            'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 3,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]
    );
}
public function createAttributeOptions($eavSetup,$attributeCode,$optionName){
      $entityType = 'catalog_product';
      $attributeInfo = $this->_eavAttribute->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);

      $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
      //$attribute_arr = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'];
      $attribute_arr = $optionName;

      $option = array();
      $option['attribute_id'] = $attributeId;
      foreach($attribute_arr as $key => $value){
          $option['value'][$value][0]=$value;
          foreach($this->_storeManager as $store){
              $option['value'][$value][$store->getId()] = $value;
          }
      }
      if ($option) {
        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
      }
  }
}
```

In the above script, I have created a csv file inside pub directory, then reading data from the file and creating the attributes based on the file data.

File content will be like this.
[image]

In database its created like below.

[image]

The problem here is the "drop down" attribute is created well, but the "source_model" is created empty in database also the backend_type created as "text" instead of "int".

Due to this we are unable to see the drop down attribute in layered navigation. Can anyone advise me here please how can i create the drop down attribute with option by reading from the csv file. Thanks!!

Comment: set backend to null (just dont set there anything)

Comment: @KonradSiamro, tried it, but that didn't work.

Comment: anyway You shouldnt set backend like that. Its Backend model, not backend type. Did u tried also to set type to varchar instead of int ?

Comment: Hi. You have received log successfully? When execute datapatch?

Comment: yes @RohanHapani, logs are working but problem with source model

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                'catalog_product',
                'attribute_code',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'My Attribute',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'default' => '',
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'searchable' => true,
                    'filterable' => true,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'option' => ['values' => ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']]
                ]
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with this below code :

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attributeCode,
        [
            'group' => 'general',
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
            'input' => 'select',
            'note' => 'My Custom Attribute',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => \MyModule\MyDropdownAttribute\Model\Config\Source\Options::class,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '0',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'option' => [ 
                'values' => [],
            ]                   
        ]
    );
```

Option File :

> **app/code/MyModule/MyDropdownAttribute/Model/Config/Source/Options.php**

```
<?php 
namespace MyModule\MyDropdownAttribute\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{ 
    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options = [ 
            ['label'=>'', 'value'=>''],
            ['label'=>'Small', 'value'=>'1'],
            ['label'=>'Medium', 'value'=>'2'],
            ['label'=>'Large', 'value'=>'3']
        ];
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You need to set your dropdown options files in source attribute. Please replace with this code and check it.

Comment: Thanks Rohan, but where is the code for options here?

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: yes @Rohan, this i got it, but if you look into my question, I am reading option from csv file, how can we map those options here? The answer you posted is to create manually one attribute with options. but in my case i am creating attributes from csv file, there may be n count.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code it will create attribute and import options using csv file

```
    <?php

public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {


        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.10') < 0) {
            $entityTypeId = $this->eavSetup->getEntityTypeId(Product::ENTITY);
            $options = $this->getCountryOptionsFromCsv('manufacturer-countries-list.csv');
            $this->addNewAttributeWithOptions($entityTypeId, 'custom_attributes_5.csv', $options);
        }




        $setup->endSetup();
    }




 private function addNewAttributeWithOptions($entityTypeId, $fileName, $options)
    {
        $ffcCatalogFixture = 'NameSpace_Catalog::fixtures/'.$fileName;
        $importFile = $this->fixtureManager->getFixture($ffcCatalogFixture);

        if (!$this->filesystem->isExists($importFile)) {
            return;
        }

        $columns = $this->csv->getData($importFile);

        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            //$this->eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE]);

            $attributeObj = $this->eavconfig->getAttribute(self::ENTITY_TYPE, self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE);
            $attributeId  =  $attributeObj->getAttributeId();
            if (!$attributeId) {
                if ($column[self::USE_IN_FILTER] == "Yes") {
                    $useInfilter = "true";
                } else {
                    $useInfilter = "false";
                }

                $usedInProductListing = ($column[self::USED_IN_PRODUCT_LISTING] == "Yes") ? true : false;

                $this->eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    Product::ENTITY,
                    $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE],
                    [
                        'global'                  => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'attribute_code'          => $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE],
                        'label'                   => $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_LABEL],
                        'attribute_model'         => '',
                        'backend'                 => $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_BACKEND],
                        'source'                  => $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE],
                        'frontend'                => '',
                        'frontend_class'          => $column[self::FRONTEND_CLASS],
                        'type'                    => $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_TYPE],
                        'input'                   => $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_INPUT],
                        'visible'                 => true,
                        'required'                => false,
                        'user_defined'            => true,
                        'searchable'              => false,
                        'filterable'              => $useInfilter,
                        'comparable'              => false,
                        'visible_on_front'        => false,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => $usedInProductListing,
                        'unique'                  => false,
                        'option' => [
                            'values' => $options,
                        ],
                    ]
                );

                // Save the attributes in attribute sets and groups.
                $attributeSets = explode(',', $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_SET]);

                foreach ($attributeSets as $attributeSet) {
                    $this->eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                        $entityTypeId,
                        $attributeSet,
                        $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_GROUP],
                        $column[self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE]
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am working on Magento 2.3, avoiding using install and upgrade schema. @hitesh

Comment: okay Please let me know if you want to import options in database so later u can manage it from admin , or you want to put as hardcoded?

Comment: need to read from csv and create it, please check my question,I have posted neatly, @hitesh